# Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in... PHP5.3, Apache2.2, Windows server 2008

Tags: php, windows, com, apache2.2

Another issue that is driving me absolutely nuts. This seems to be a common error that I have not been able to fix with "traditional" methods (answers provided by others for the same issue)..

Windows 2008 R2 - x64

Apache 2.2.25

PHP 5.3.27

I have these lines in my php.ini:

```
extension_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\"
[COM_DOT_NET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

php_com_dotnet.dll exists in that directory, I even took it one step further and tried assigning read permission to Everyone for the PHP folder although it should have access just fine as it does load other libraries in there.

Below is the configure command from phpinfo() which is really the only thing mentioning COM.

> cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build"
>   "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--without-mssql"
>   "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web"
>   "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared"
>   "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared"
>   "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared"
>   "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" **"--enable-com-dotnet=shared"**
>   "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze"

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thanks

EDIT

```
get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path') = C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini
```

Which is the php.ini I have edited.

Also, here is the error log, nothing pointing to an issue....

```
[Mon Mar 31 14:51:09 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) PHP/5.3.27 mod_aspdotnet/2.2 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Mon Mar 31 14:51:09 2014] [notice] Server built: Jul 10 2013 01:52:12

[Mon Mar 31 14:51:09 2014] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3708

[Mon Mar 31 14:51:09 2014] [notice] mod_aspdotnet: CorBindToRuntimeEx has loaded version v2.0.50727 of the .NET CLR engine.

[Mon Mar 31 14:51:40 2014] [notice] Child 3708: Child process is running

[Mon Mar 31 14:51:40 2014] [notice] Child 3708: Acquired the start mutex.

[Mon Mar 31 14:51:40 2014] [notice] Child 3708: Starting 250 worker threads.

[Mon Mar 31 14:51:40 2014] [notice] Child 3708: Starting thread to listen on port 8086.

[Mon Mar 31 14:51:40 2014] [notice] Child 3708: Starting thread to listen on port 8084.
```

Comment: Have you double-checked you did edit the right php.ini via `echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer - just trying to get more data
What's the output of

```
<?php
$config = file(get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path'));
foreach( $config as $n=>$l) {
    if ( false!==strpos($l, 'dotnet') ) {
        printf("%03d %s<br />\r\n", $n, $l);
    }
}
echo 'com_dotnet: ', extension_loaded('com_dotnet') ? 'yes':'no', "<br />\r\n";
echo 'class: ', class_exists('COM')  ? 'yes':'no', "<br />\r\n";
```

?

**UPDATE: (answer from comments)**

The answer seemed to be a corrupt or somehow "bad" php_com_dotnet.dll, which the windows installer did not replace. I simply grabbed the matching version binary zip, overwrote the dll by hand - VOILA! Marking your answer as the answer since it was the closest and got me on the right track.

Comment: 1918 extension=php_com_dotnet.dll 

com_dotnet: no

class: no

Comment: when you start the httpd directly from a command line (not as a service, not by some helper tool) are there any warnings printed to the console?

Comment: interesting... "httpd.exe - Entry Point Not Found - The procedure entry point zend_new_interned_string could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll. "
"

Comment: hm, not what I've expected, I was looking for something like `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library ...` Your warning might have been covered under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154016/entry-point-error-when-running-php-script-from-command-line

Comment: hmm yea none of those suggestions worked although I am running zend. I found another forum mentioning the php5ts.dll may have become corrupt I am going to try reinstalling that instance of apache.

Comment: I updated PHP to the latest windows installer - 5.3.28, This seemed to fix the issue when starting httpd.exe directly but still the same initial issue. If you have any other suggestions, great, if not thanks for this good insight. I can't vote up yet...

Comment: The answer seemed to be a corrupt or somehow "bad" php_com_dotnet.dll, which the windows installer did not replace. I simply grabbed the matching version binary zip, overwrote the dll by hand - VOILA! Marking your answer as the answer since it was the closest and got me on the right track.